# rails 5 routing, PUT action winds up as GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

using acts_as_votable gem to upvote/downvote a "skill", 
rails 5.0.0 app

routes.rb:

```
  resources :skills do
    member do
      patch "upvote", to: "skills#upvote"
      put "downvote", to: "skills#downvote"
    end
  end
```

skills controller:

```
  def upvote
    @skill.upvote_from current_user
    redirect_to skill_path(@skill.id)
  end

  def downvote
    @skill.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to skill_path(@skill.id)
  end
```

the view:

```
<%= link_to "Up Vote", upvote_skill_path(skill), method: :put %>
```

generates this HTML:

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="put" href="/skills/98/upvote">Up Vote</a>
```

but when clicking the link, somehow its a GET:

```
Started GET "/skills/98/upvote" for 192.168.0.2 at 2017-02-23 22:46:07 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/skills/98/upvote"):
```

'rake routes' output looks right:

```
  upvote_skill PUT    /skills/:id/upvote(.:format)      skills#upvote
  downvote_skill PUT    /skills/:id/downvote(.:format)    skills#downvote
```

Im at a loss.. the only thing I can think is this app started life out as an API only app  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html but I am pretty sure I have followed all the convert "regular app to API" steps by doing section 3.2 backwards.  But maybe I am missing something ?

Comment: I think you have a typo error, because you have defined twice `upvote` in your controller

Comment: Is any js code intercepting the click event on the a element? If it is, and did an e.preventDefault / e.stopPropagation then it may then be firing a GET and ignoring your data-method="put".

Comment: thanks @rogelio fixed that, but no change.

Comment: no .js on the page doing anything near that link. @Chris Cousins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails uses unobtrusive javascript to perform this type of actions, probably you don't have included the javascript correctly, because your app started as api-only and `assets` and `views` are not included in this mode.

In your `application.html.erb` ensure you are including the javascript

```
<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

You application.js must have at least these definitions

```
// app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

finally, the `Gemfile` needs

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Then: bundle, reload the server and test again.

Comment: yeah, this was it.  uggh..  definitely some leftovers from converting from an API only app to a full rails app. working as expected now.  Thanks !

Comment: yep, maybe you have more missing things because this conversion.